issue with python script to reduce jpm images
I'm on windows 11, using a Python script to compress JPG images recursively in a folder and its subfolders. The script uses the Pillow library and is designed to reduce image quality by 70% while replacing the original files. However, I'm encountering an issue where the script suddenly stops processing in the middle of execution without any error message.
Here's the script I'm using:
import os
from PIL import Image

def compress_images(directory, quality):
    """
    Recursively compresses all JPG images in a directory and its subdirectories.
    
    Args:
        directory (str): Path of the directory to process
        quality (int): Quality of the compressed image (1-100)
    """
    # Convert path to absolute format
    directory = os.path.abspath(directory)
    
    # Counter for processed images
    processed = 0
    
    # Iterate through all files in directory and subdirectories
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            # Check if file is a JPG image
            if filename.lower().endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg')):
                filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                try:
                    # Open the image
                    with Image.open(filepath) as img:
                        # Check if image is in RGB mode
                        if img.mode in ('RGBA', 'P'):
                            img = img.convert('RGB')
                        
                        # Save compressed image overwriting the original
                        img.save(filepath, 'JPEG', quality=quality, optimize=True)
                    
                    processed += 1
                    print(f"Compressed: {filepath}")
                    
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error processing {filepath}: {str(e)}")
    
    return processed

# Directory path to process
directory = r"C:\Users\TESTA LORENZO\Desktop\foto camion"

# Calculate quality (30% of original = 70% reduction)
quality = 30

# Run compression
try:
    num_processed = compress_images(directory, quality)
    print(f"\nCompression completed!")
    print(f"Number of images processed: {num_processed}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")


The script works fine initially and processes some images, but then it just stops at a random point. No error messages are displayed nor useful logs, it just freezes and doesn't continue processing the remaining images.
I tried adding more logs but no errors appear. It also doesn't use much memory while working
Any idea why it might be stopping unexpectedly?

Are there any symlinks in the directory or subdirectiories that could send os.walk() running in circles?

Try printing the name of the file you are processing before you open it, or use your debugger. Checking for RGBA and Palette mode images doesn't seem very sensible with JPEGs which support neither alpha nor palette images. If you have lots of images, you should consider using multiprocessing. Your whole script can be done with a single ImageMagick command and no Python, by the way.

@MarkSetchell oh I didn't know about that program, thank you!

@ilikeMUDs I'll check, maybe that's the reason
